# How to get id of various buttons on click in android and perform various operations

Tags: android, xml, api

I have attached ss of my layout file.[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXnKP.png)

**now when user clicks on cse I want to connect with api related to cse ,similarly when mech is clicked I want to connect with the api related to mech and vice versa how can do these all in single activity using any condition statement**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement on click listener.

```
class DepartmentActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
...
}
```

```
  override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when(view.id)
        {
            R.id.btnCse -> // call the required  method
            R.id.btnMech -> // call the required  method
            R.id.btnEce -> // call the required  method
            R.id.btnErr -> // call the required  method
        }
    }
```